# gulp.dest() is not creating an output file

Tags: gulp

I have the following code in a gulp task. It's not writing an output file.

```
  const player = {
    player: {
      src: 'x',
      tpl: '<style>%s</style>'
    }
  }
  gulp.src('.src/index.html')
    .pipe(replace(player))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./app/));
```

Answer (score 1):

This has one of those 'well duh' answers. You've left a slash out of your source path. It should be `./src/index.html`. Since `gulp.src()` doesn't throw an error, it doesn't occur to you to check it.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues in your code.

---

**1. Incorrect path**

Your first mistake is that you have gotten an incorrect path.

In the `gulp.src()` function, you are passing a path to a folder called `.src`. However, it is most likely supposed to be redirecting to `./src`. See the code below for the solution.

```js
gulp.src("./src/index.html");
```

---

**2. Missing end quote (`"`)**

Your other mistake is that you've forgotten to end your `string` in the `.pipe()` method (the second one).

The code below should work properly.

```js
.pipe("./app/");
```

---

In conclusion, there were two issues in your code.

1. Incorrect path
2. Missing end quote (`"`)

When these two are fixed, your code should run correctly.